# Search any .qgs file in Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

In **[Actions]** How do I refer to **any file** with the **.qgs** ending within the county folder? (rather than need to specify a specific file .qgs?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`endswith('.qgs')`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm) string method on the file name string

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot without seeing the files, maybe you can print the `names` variable inside the ´for´ loop, are there actually any .qgs files in there?